# How I can I make my articles show the "View article" preview on Google Inbox?

Tags: gmail, json-ld

I've setup [my site](https://rebelliard.com/blog/react-driven-by-facebook-principle-concerns) to show previews on Facebook, Twitter Cards and other services using OpenGraph, but I'm wondering what is necessary to make my articles show a "Go to action" on Inbox when they're shared?

[image: Article preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the Gmail > Markup > [View Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action) markup to your content.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "target": "https://watch-movies.com/watch?movieId=abc123",
    "name": "Watch movie"
  },
  "description": "Watch the 'Avengers' movie online"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Would this add the preview when a user shares a link by email? I just tried it and it did not, although I'm not sure if Google takes its time starting to render these.

Comment: There is usually a site-crawling delay of a few days.  Yes, this adds a preview and an action (in this case View Action) to the email.  See the Action Overview: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview